# Class Object Begineer :- AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sit_down' how to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Robot:
def __init__(self, name, color, weight):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.weight = weight

def introduce_self(self):
    print("My name is " + self.name)
    print("My color is " + self.color)
    print("My height is " + srt(self.height))
```

r1 = Robot("Tom", "Red", 30)
r2 = Robot("Jerry", "Blue", 40)

class Person:
    def **init**(self, name, personality, issitting):
        self.name = name
        self.personality = personality
        self.issitting = issitting

```
def sit_down(self):
    self.sitdown = True

def stand_up(self):
    self.standup = False
```

p1 = Person("Alice", "Aggresive", False)
p2 = Person("Beacky", "Talkative", True)

p1.robot_owned = r2
p2.robot_owned = r1

p1.robot_owned.introduce_self.sit_down()

Comment: please make the question clearer

Comment: there is no particular question, I took some random inputs and made 2 class with different attributes, and finally i want to call the function for either class or something from both classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont chain introduce_self()
and sit_down().Seperate them into two statements

```
p1.robot_owned.sit_down()
p1.robot_owned.introduce_self()
```

Comment: This error is showing after the change

My name is Jerry
My color is Blue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sujoy/Desktop/PY-codes/multipleclassobject.py", line 34, in <module>
    p1.robot_owned.introduce_self()
  File "/home/sujoy/Desktop/PY-codes/multipleclassobject.py", line 10, in introduce_self
    print("My height is " + srt(self.height))
NameError: name 'srt' is not defined

Comment: Change srt to str

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sujoy/Desktop/PY-codes/multipleclassobject.py", line 34, in <module>
    p1.robot_owned.introduce_self()
  File "/home/sujoy/Desktop/PY-codes/multipleclassobject.py", line 10, in introduce_self
    print("My height is " + str(self.height))
AttributeError: 'Robot' object has no attribute 'height'

Comment: change the weight in the constructor to height ```def __init__(self, name, color, height):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.height = height```

Comment: This last error

p1.robot_owned.sit_down()
AttributeError: 'Robot' object has no attribute 'sit_down'

Comment: Because robot class doesnt have a method sit_down

Comment: ```p1.sit_down()``` instead